# How do i extract specific data from a file?

Tags: c#

I have a file which has temperature data in it . I need to extract temperature from it and save the result with only temperatures in a new file.

This is the contents of the file :

```
BCAST:000D6F00017620E9, 02=34.23
BCAST:000D6F00017620E9, 02=12.3
BCAST:000D6F00017620E9, 02=54.01
BCAST:000D6F00017620E9, 02=12.34
BCAST:000D6F00017620E9, 02=16.22
```

Need to extract the data after every = i.e 34.23,12.3,54.01 etc

I have tried using sub string but it can be used when i read the file as a string and it just makes a substring of first line , rest remains same.Following is my code.Please suggest !

```
string temp2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:********\temperature.txt");
int c = temp2.IndexOf("=");
string temp3 = temp2.Substring(c + 1);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\*******\temperature2.txt",temp3);
```

Output of this code is :

```
34.23
BCAST:000D6F00017620E9, 02=12
BCAST:000D6F00017620E9, 02=54
BCAST:000D6F00017620E9, 02=12
BCAST:000D6F00017620E9, 02=16
```

Comment: hint: use some sort of loop to process each line of the file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ReadAllText` will return the entire file as one string. It would make more sense to loop on an array of lines and use your substring code on each line.

**EDIT** ReadAllLines is a static call:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```

Or, read one line at a time with a stream:

```
var sr = new StreamReader(fileStream);
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
  var line = sr.ReadLine();
  // .. per line sub string
}
```

**EDIT 2** I worked out a complete solution (note I prefer stream reading as opposed to read-all styles - it is more efficient for very large files - so it's a good practice to get used to)

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

using (var file = new FileStream("C:/tmp/temps.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  var sr = new StreamReader(file);

  while (!sr.EndOfStream)
  {
    var nextLine = sr.ReadLine();
    int indexOfEqualSign = nextLine.IndexOf("=");

    if (indexOfEqualSign == -1 || indexOfEqualSign == nextLine.Length)
      continue;

    string rightHandSide = nextLine.Substring(indexOfEqualSign + 1);
    sb.AppendLine(rightHandSide);
  }
}

File.WriteAllText("C:/tmp/temps2.txt", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but you need to loop through the lines in the file and then do a split on the =:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\********\temperature.txt"); 
StringBuilder temperatures = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] parts = line.Split('=');

    if (lines.Length > 1)
    {
        tempatures.Append(lines[1]));
        tempatures.Append("\n");
    }
}

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\*******\temperature2.txt", tempatures.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Read each line at a time, split on the equal sign.
Be sure to include: System.IO for the StreamReader

```
try
{
    // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
    // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:********\temperature.txt"))
    {
        String line;
        // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
        // the file is reached.
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line.Split('=')[1]);
            } 
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Contained No equals sign: " + line);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Let the user know what went wrong.
    Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
string readFile =  @"C:\****\temperature.txt");
string writeFile = @"C:\****\temperature2.txt");
List<string> lines = new List<string>lines;
....
string sr = new StreamReader(readFile);
foreach (string line in sr.ReadAllLines())
{
   int c = line.IndexOf("=");
   if ( c >= 0 ) {
      lines.Add(line.SubString(c+1);
   }
}

if ( lines.Count > 0 ) {
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(writeFile, 
     string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.ToArray*());
}
```